# How do I return the next array when a button is pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I'm new to programming and Swift and have been following along with a tutorial. I'm learning about the MVC design pattern and I have a function that changes the Title label and Button labels when a button is pressed. Once we get to Story 1 or Story 2 and we select any of the choices, I want it to restart to Story 0 and the original choices. However, when the story changes to Story 1, choice2 triggers Story 2 and when the story changes to Story 2, choice1 triggers Story1. I want it to reset to Story 0 when any choice is chosen. I tried to modify the nextStory function but have been unsuccessful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.!

**Model:**

```
struct StoryBrain {

    var storyNumber = 0

    let story = [Story(t: "You see a fork in the road.", c1: "Take a left.", c2: "Take a right."),
                 Story(t: "You see a tiger.", c1: "Shout for help.", c2: "Play dead."),
                 Story(t: "You find a treasure chest", c1: "Open it.", c2: "Check for traps.")
    ]

    func getStoryTitle() -> String {
        return story[storyNumber].title
    }

    func getChoice1() -> String {
        return story[storyNumber].choice1
    }

    func getChoice2() -> String {
        return story[storyNumber].choice2
    }

    mutating func nextStory(_ userChoice: String) {
        if userChoice == story[storyNumber].choice1 {
            storyNumber = 1
        } else if userChoice == story[storyNumber].choice2 {
            storyNumber = 2
        }


    }

}
```

**View Controller**

```
@IBAction func choiceMade(_ sender: UIButton) {

        storyBrain.nextStory(sender.currentTitle!)
        updateUI()

    }

    func updateUI() {
        storyLabel.text = storyBrain.getStoryTitle()
        choice1Button.setTitle(storyBrain.getChoice1(), for: .normal)
        choice2Button.setTitle(storyBrain.getChoice2(), for: .normal)
    }
```

Comment: what issue you are facing ?

Comment: Why not use Array[Dictionaries] instead of the Story Object ? You will be able to locate the key in every item and depending on the key comparison can reset the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If storyNumber i**s** 0 then check choice for update next story.
If storyNumber **is not** 0 it might be 1 or 2 you should reset story to 0.

```
mutating func nextStory(_ userChoice: String) {
    if storyNumber == 0 {
        if userChoice == story[storyNumber].c1 {
            storyNumber = 1
        } else if userChoice == story[storyNumber].c2 {
            storyNumber = 2
        }
    } else {
        storyNumber = 0
    }
}
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, I am understanding you correctly. You just want to restart once you reach story 2.

```
mutating func nextStory(_ userChoice: String) {
    guard storyNumber != 0 else { storyNumber = 0; return }

        if userChoice == story[storyNumber].choice1 {
            storyNumber = 1
            return
        } else if userChoice == story[storyNumber].choice2 {
            storyNumber = 2
            return
        }
    }
```

Hopefully, something like this works for you. Just off the top of my head.